# Javascript compiler in C?

Tags: javascript, c

I'm looking for a simple (preferably C-based) Javascript compiler that I can use to determine if a chunk of Javascript contains any syntax errors, and the location (line number) of those errors. Is there a small library that anyone knows of that I can use to do something like this?

Comment: I thought jslint/jshint was used for syntax checking, among other things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) isn't good enough for you?

Comment: V8 won in the end, primarily because of its relatively small size compared to Spidermonkey.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) by Mozilla